# .htaccess rewrite for for localhost port mapping?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to catch a route `some_path` on my website and redirect it to a different port on the same server. The following code works on the server, but not on my localhost box. I'm using Ubuntu

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    # Works on the server
    RewriteRule ^some_path/(.*)$ http://remoteserver.com:1337/$1 [P,L]

    # Does not work on the localhost
    RewriteRule ^some_local_path/(.*)$ http://localhost:1337/$1 [P,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect 2 things:

1. You don't have mod_proxy enabled on local Ubuntu
2. You may not have anything running on port # 1337

Comment: mod_proxy_http was the final kicker. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to have mod_proxy loaded. If mod_proxy isn't loaded, the `P` flag won't proxy, it'll simply redirect.